# How do I translate the intersection of two affine curves in a plane into a statement about ideals in $k[X, Y]$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, classical-algebraic-geometry

Let $E : y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$ be an elliptic curve over a field $k$ with characteristic not $2$ or $3$ (not necessarily algebraically closed), and let $x = x_0$ be a line that intersects $E$ in $(x_0, \pm y_0) \in E(k)$.

According to Lemma 10 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2302.10640.pdf), this is expressed algebraically as the following equation of ideals over $k[X, Y]$:
$$
(X - x_0, Y - y_0) (X - x_0, Y + y_0) \equiv (X - x_0) \pmod{(Y^2 - (X^3 + AX + B))},
$$
or more directly
$$
(X - x_0, Y - y_0) (X - x_0, Y + y_0) = (X - x_0, Y^2 - (X^3 + AX + B)).
$$

The paper gives a purely algebraic proof of this statement, although I can't help but think there must be a way to derive this algebro-geometrically.

I'd imagine it'd go something like:
$$
V((X - x_0, Y - y_0) (X - x_0, Y + y_0)) = \\{ (x_0, \pm y_0) \\} = 
V(X - x_0, Y^2 - (X^3 + AX + B))
$$
We'd like to conclude that
$$
(X - x_0, Y - y_0) (X - x_0, Y + y_0) = (X - x_0, Y^2 - (X^3 + AX + B)).
$$

I know that $V(I) = V(J)$ doesn't imply $I = J$ in general; the most common condition is that $I$ and $J$ are radical ideals, and $k$ has to be algebraically closed, and then we can use the Nullstellensatz directly.

It seems doable to show that $(X - x_0, Y - y_0) (X - x_0, Y + y_0)$ is radical, via
$$
\sqrt{I J} = \sqrt{I \cap J} = \sqrt{I} \cap \sqrt{J}
$$
but it seems less obvious that $(X - x_0, Y^2 - (X^3 + AX + B))$ is radical. (Edit: It now seems doable by showing that $k[X, Y]/(X - x_0, Y^2 - (X^3 + AX + B))$ is reduced.)

Also, even if we assume that $k$ is algebraically closed and use the Nullstellensatz, maybe we can extend this to non-algebraically closed subfields of $k$ given some conditions, e.g. if the points of intersection are in the subfield. (Edit: [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1440759/343314) seems to be what I need.)

Am I on the right track?

Comment: The ideal $(X - x_0, Y - y_0)$ is well-defined only over the residue field $k(y_0)$ or its extensions. And if you want these ideals to be radical then $\text{char}(k)\neq2$. You may presumably take $(x_0,y_0)$ to be a $k$-rational point and $k$ is not of char 2.

Comment: Anyway $(X - x_0, Y^2 - (X^3 + AX + B))=I$ is radical. To see this let $(X - x_0, Y - y_0)=M,(X - x_0, Y + y_0)=N$, they are maximal ideals in $k[x,y]$. Since $MN\subset I$, That means $M,N$ show up in some primary decomposition of $I$. Hence the prime divisors of $I$ contain $M,N$ and if there's another one $p=\sqrt{Q}$, then $MN\subset I\subset MNQ$. It follows $I=MN$.

Comment: If $y_0\notin k $ then $M'=(X-x_0, y^2-y_0^2)$ is a maximal ideal and $(X - x_0, Y^2 - (X^3 + AX + B))=M'$ is also radical. But now $(X - x_0, Y - y_0) (X - x_0, Y + y_0)$ isn't an ideal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll didn't think of using primary decomposition, I'll try that.

I don't follow some of what you said though. I'm assuming $x_0, y_0 \in k$; in that case surely $(X - x_0, Y - y_0)$ is well-defined as an ideal of $k[X, Y]$?

Comment: @FredAkalin - when asking questions about online papers - define things properly and explain the notation. Then you may get more response.

Comment: @hm2020 what part of my question in particular wasn't defined properly or which notation wasn't explained?

Comment: @FredAkalin - is your field $k$ algebraically closed? When $k$ is algebraically closed and you work using the language of "classical algebraic varieties", you may (by the Nullstellensatz) say that any point $p \in E$ in an affine chart of an elliptic curve $E \subseteq \mathbb{A}^2_k$ corresponds to a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}:=(x-a,y-b) \subseteq R$ where $x,y$ are local coordinates and where $R$ is the coordinate ring of $E$. Is this what you speak of?

Comment: $k$ isn't necessarily algebraically closed, although that wasn't clear without reading the whole question, so I edit it to mention it earlier.

You're definitely right about the case where $k$ is algebraically closed, and I think I can convince myself that it's extendable non-algebraically-closed subfields (if the points are in the subfield).

Comment: @FredAkalin - when you write $I:=(x-x_0,y-y_0)$ and if $x_0,y_0 \in k$ it follows $I$ is a maximal ideal in your coordinate ring $R:=\Gamma(E, \mathcal{O}_E)$. Note that this does not give all maximal ideals in $R$ since $k$ is not algebraically closed. Hence if your aim is to give an "elementary formula" expressing the addition map on $E$, this will fail.

Comment: @FredAkalin: If $x \in E$ is a closed point with residue field $k \subsetneq k(x)$ a strict inclusion , you may not write $m_x:=(x-a, y-b)$ with $a,b \in k(x)$. An elliptic curve $E$ is an abelian variety in the following sense: If $k \subseteq K$ is a field extension and if $x,y \in E(K)$ are points defined over $K$, you may add $x$ and $y$ to another point $x+y \in E(K)$. But if $x,y \in E$ are closed point with different residue fields  you may not "add them".

Comment: This is expressed as following: The functor of points of an elliptic curve $E/k$ is a functor $h_E: k-alg \rightarrow Groups$ taking a $k$-algebra $A$ to a group $h_E(S):=Mor_k(S,E)$ with $S:=Spec(A)$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really following what you're saying. I merely wish to prove the identity as written, or rather to find a different proof for it (since the paper already furnishes one).

Comment: @FredAkalin - Let us  assume $y_0 \neq 0$ and let $I:=(x-x_0,y-y_0), J:=(x-x_0,y+y_0)$ and $N:=(x-x_0)$. Let $A:=k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-Ax-B)$. You are trying to prove there is an equality of ideals $IJ = N$ in $A$. The ring $A/N \cong k[y]/(y^2-f(x_0))$, and this ring is a field if $f(x_0)$ is not a square in $k$. The ideals $I,J$ are coprime maximal ideals,hence the ring $A/IJ \cong A/I \oplus A/J \cong k \oplus k$ which is never a field.  Hence it seems the claimed equality is not correct.

Comment: If $(x_0, y_0) \in E(k)$ doesn't it follow that $f(x_0)$ is a square in $k$, i.e. $y_0^2 = f(x_0)$? I suppose I wasn't clear about that -- edited to clarify.

Comment: (Also, I guess that explains my earlier confusion with what Lucellia was saying.)

Comment: @FredAkalin - the case when $y_0=0$ needs to be treated separately, I included an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all of this is fine. If two ideals have the same zero set, then their radicals are equal, so if both ideals are radical, they are the same. It's not difficult to see that both of your ideals are radical by showing that the quotients by them are reduced:

- For the case of $I=(x-x_0,y-y_0)(x-x_0,y+y_0)$, the ideals $(x-x_0,y-y_0)$ and $(x-x_0,y+y_0)$ are comaximal, as $(y+y_0)-(y-y_0)=2y_0$, which is a unit as $2\neq 0$ and $y_0\neq 0$ by the assumption that the line intersects the elliptic curve in two points. Therefore $k[x,y]/I\cong k[x,y]/(x-x_0,y-y_0) \times k[x,y]/(x-x_0,y+y_0)\cong k\times k$ which is reduced.
- For the case of $J=(x-x_0,y^2-(x^3+Ax+B))$, we have $k[x,y]/J\cong k[y]/(y^2-(x_0^3+Ax_0+B))$, and $x_0^3+Ax_0+B$ is a nonzero square by the assumption that the line intersects the elliptic curve in two $k$-rational points. So $k[x,y]/J\cong k[y]/(y^2-c^2)$ for some $c\neq 0$, and as we're not in characteristic two, $y^2-c^2=(y-c)(y+c)$, and again $k[y]/(y-c)(y+c)\cong k\times k$ by the Chinese remainder theorem.

This will work correctly when $k$ is not algebraically closed assuming you can fix the nullstellensatz to remove the "algebraically closed" assumption. The right way of doing this is by using schemes, which add enough extra info that you can make that upgrade. (Another way to do this is that you see sometimes in print is to work with things defined over $k$ but look at their zero sets over $\overline{k}$.)

Answer (score -2):

**Comment:** "@FredAkalin - Let us assume $y_0≠0$ and let $I:=(x−x_0,y−y_0),J:=(x−x_0,y+y_0)$ and $N:=(x−x_0)$. Let $A:=k[x,y]/(y^2−x^3−Ax−B)$. You are trying to prove there is an equality of ideals $IJ=N$ in $A$. The ring $A/N≅k[y]/(y^2−f(x_0))$, and this ring is a field if $f(x_0)$ is not a square in $k$. The ideals $I,J$ are coprime maximal ideals,hence the ring $A/IJ≅A/I⊕A/J≅k⊕k$ which is never a field. Hence it seems the claimed equality is not correct.

**Response**: If $(x_0,y_0)∈E(k)$ doesn't it follow that $f(x_0)$ is a square in $k$, i.e. $y^2_0=f(x_0)$? I suppose I wasn't clear about that -- edited to clarify.

**Answer:** You must be careful when working with maximal ideals in the ring $A$.

Let $I:=(x−x_0,y−y_0),J:=(x−x_0,y+y_0)$ and $N:=(x−x_0)$ with $(x_0,y_0) \in E(k)$ be $k$-rational points. Since $I$ and $J$ are coprime maximal ideals (if $char(k) \neq 2$) it follows $A/IJ \cong k \oplus k$ and this ring has no nilpotents. Let us consider $A/N$. We get the following

$$A/(x-x_0) \cong k[y]/(y^2-f(x_0))$$

and we have the following equality of ideals in $k[y]$:

$$(y-y_0)(y+y_0)=(y^2-y_0^2)=(y^2-f(x_0))$$

hence

$$A/(x-x_0) \cong k[y]/(y^2-f(x_0)) \cong k[y]/(y-y_0)(y+y_0) \cong k \oplus k$$

if $y_0 \neq 0$. This is because $(x_0,y_0)\in E(k)$ and hence $y_0^2=f(x_0)$.

You get an exact sequence

$$0 \rightarrow N \rightarrow A \stackrel{\rho}\rightarrow k \oplus k \rightarrow 0$$

And the map $\rho$ sends the ideal $IJ$ to the following ideal:

$$\rho(IJ)= (x_0-x_0, y-y_0)(x_0-x_0, y+y_0) =(y-y_0)(y+y_0)=0 $$

Hence there is an iduced map $A/IJ \cong k \oplus k \rightarrow A/N \cong k \oplus k$ which is an isomorphism.

If $y_0=0$ it follows $IJ:=(x-x_0, y)^2 \neq (x-x_0):=N,$

hence the ideals are not equal.  Hence the following holds in general (over any field of $char(k) \neq 2$).

Summing up: 1. If $(x_0,y_0) \in E(k)$ and if $y_0^2 \neq 0$ it follows there is an equality of ideals $IJ =N$ in $A$.

2. If $y_0=0, f(x_0)=0$ it follows $IJ \neq N$.

Note: There is a "maximal spectrum" defined for an affine (or quasi projective ) algebraic variety over a non algebraically closed field. This may have some interest:

[Grothendieck point of view of algebraic geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3906932/grothendieck-point-of-view-of-algebraic-geometry/3997811#3997811)

Im unsure what is your background, but the notion "algebraic variety" as defined in Hartshornes book "Algebraic geometry" chapter I, needs the base field to be algebraically closed. Over a non algebraically closed field $k$ there is no 1-1 correspondence between maximal ideals in $A$ and points $(x_0,y_0) \in k^2$ with $y^2_0=f(x_0)$.

The above link defines a "max spectrum" for your ring $A$ when $k$ is non algebraically closed.  Using this the construction in the link you may speak of lines, tangents etc.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I follow the $y_0 = 0$ case. I agree that $A/N$ has nilpotent elements, but since $y_0 = 0$, $I = J$, and so $I$ and $J$ are not comaximal anymore, and thus we can't conclude that $A/IJ = A/I^2$ is congruent to $k \oplus k$, and thus doesn't have nilpotent elements.

Comment: Also note that Lemma 10 of the linked paper provides a formally-checked proof using straightforward ideal properties of a generalization of the statement which doesn't rely on $y_0$ being non-zero, so unless I missed something in my simplification (which is not unlikely), or this paper is wrong, I'm a bit skeptical that the statement is false.

Comment: @FredAkalin - the point I'm trying to make is: It does not make any sense to speak of "lines", "tangents" and other "geometric properties" in the above case if you use the language in HH, CHI and when $k$ is not algebraically closed. The language in HH CHI needs $k$ to be algebraically closed. In the above case you need another construction - the link gives such a construction.

Comment: We may be talking past each other, but my issue is with the claim that "If $y_0=0,f(x_0)=0$
 it follows $IJ≠N$". I agree with the general point that working with non-algebraically-closed needs special tools, or passing to the algebraic closure.

Comment: @FredAkalin - If $y_0=0$ it follows $IJ:=(x-x_0,y)^2 \neq (x-x_0):=N$ hence the two ideals are not equal. The linked paper speaks of "elliptic curves" and an "elementary formula" for the group law on such a curve. If the authors do not work over an algebraically closed field, they cannot use the theory in HH CHI. They need something else.

Comment: @FredAkalin - this case seems to be uninteresting since you speak of a "line" "intersecting" the "curve" in 2 "different points". Again: You need $k$ to be algebraically closed in order to use HH CHI and to do this.

Comment: I've verified to my satisfaction that $(x - x_0, y)^2 = (x - x_0)$ in $A$, simply by expressing the generators in one side in terms of the other; the proof in the paper is along the same lines. The proof doesn't rely on $k$ being algebraically closed. So I disagree with your claim, and besides you haven't addressed the issue I pointed out in your earlier claimed disproof.

You seem to be getting hung up on the geometric language used in the first paragraph. If you'd like, you can ignore it, and treat the question purely in ring-theoretic terms.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at the problem, but I'm not sure if further discussion would be fruitful, especially since I already had my original question answered.